# CABasicAnimation for mask that contains a gradient for covering and uncovering a view when it's height changes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mask, cabasicanimation

I'm currently working on an iOS app in Swift, which requires a feature where an arrow (UIButton) is clicked to reveal more text and the gradient that is covering the text slowly uncovers the text as the height of the label increases.  Basically I have created a container view with a mask that contains a gradient, and inside the container is the UILabel that contains the text which gets covered by the gradient and expands in height when the height of the container expands.  I'm currently able to animate the containers height increasing and the text uncovering, however I can't animate the mask of the container that contains the gradient.  Here is my code written in Swift 4;

```
 //old bounds of the container
 var oldBounds = self.authourBlurbContainer.layer.mask!.bounds

//new bounds of the container
var newBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.authourBlurbContainer.frame.width, height: 
self.authorDescriptionLabel.text!.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: 
self.authorDescriptionLabel.frame.width, font: UIFont(name: "Georgia", 
size: 23.0)!))

//Create the animation
let layerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
        layerAnimation.duration = 2
        layerAnimation.fromValue = oldBounds
        layerAnimation.toValue = newBounds
        layerAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: 
CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        layerAnimation.fillMode = .forwards

  // Update the bounds so the layer doesn't snap back when the 
  animation completes
 self.authourBlurbContainer.layer.mask!.bounds = newBounds

self.authourBlurbContainer.layer.mask!.add(layerAnimation, forKey: 
  "bounds")


//Animation to increase the height of the container and display all the 
text in the UILabel
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], 
animations: {

            //Set the height
            self.blurbContainerHeight.constant = 
(self.authorDescriptionLabel.text!.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: 
self.authorDescriptionLabel.frame.width, font: UIFont(name: "Georgia", 
size: 23.0)!))

self.authourBlurbContainer.layer.mask!.add(layerAnimation, forKey: 
"bounds")


            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (finished) in

        }
```